# sed remove everything after "WORD" until the last "-" per line, keep "WORD" and "-"

Tags: sed

I'm writing a script and I need to remove parts of a filename.

I need to remove everything between `REMUX` and the last `-` in the line

I have:

> ```
> Movie/TV-Show S01 1080p BluRay REMUX VC-1 DD+ 5.1 -RlsGroup
> ```

```
sed -E -i 's/REMUX.*\-//' $file
```

gives me:

```
Movie/TV-Show S01 1080p BluRay RlsGroup
```

but I want to keep the "REMUX" and the last "-"

```
Movie/TV-Show S01 1080p BluRay REMUX -RlsGroup
```

can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 2):

Just:

```
sed -i -e 's/REMUX.*-/REMUX -/' -- "$file"
```

Comment: thx that works great

Comment: @scr44tch You may want to look at
https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers, and also take the
tour: https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour (you'll receive a badge when
you've done so).